# R - create batch files

Tags: r, cmd

I created batch file that runs my R reports. Currently I have batch file that loads R script, something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.0\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" "D:\Batch reports\r_files\daily.R" 
pause()
```

As you can see, this command loads daily.R file from D drive. Content of this file usually looks like this. It loads my custom R library where reports are stored as R functions. This functions usualy have several parameters.

```
library(myReports)

sales_report(country = "usa", year = 2019, filter_amounts >= 1000, currency = "usd")
sales_report(country = "uk", year > 2010, currency = "gbp")
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to have only batch file without extra .R file. For this I would need to put content of .R file to batch file. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: maybe from the command line `R -e 'library(myReports);sales_report........'`

Comment: `pause()` is not a batch file command, it's `pause`...